# OpenCv 2.4.3: can't find imread and SurfFeatureDetector::detect

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, osx-snow-leopard

on Mac OSX 10.8, XCode 4.6, in C++

I'm following the tutorial in `opencv_tutorials.pdf`, located in `/opt/local/share/OpenCV/doc` on my system.  On page 311, we get this sample (slightly edited):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
using namespace cv; 
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  Mat img_1 = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
  int minHessian = 400;
  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
  detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
}
```

I had to modify the code above to `#include "opencv2/nonFree/features2d.hpp"`, a file that I found by running

```
find /opt/local/include -name "*.hpp" -exec grep SurfFeatureDetector "{}" ';' -print
```

The code compiles, meaning that the symbol `detector.detect` is found in the `hpp` file and passes type-checking by the C++ compiler.  Next is to try to find the libraries that contain the symbols.

Now, I have these libraries in my distribution, in `/opt/local/lib`:

```
libopencv_calib3d.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_contrib.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_core.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_features2d.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_flann.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_gpu.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_highgui.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_legacy.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_ml.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_nonfree.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_objdetect.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_photo.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_stitching.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_ts.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_video.2.4.3.dylib
libopencv_videostab.2.4.3.dylib
```

I found it uninformative to `nm` search these for the required symbols because name mangling is difficult to decompile in my head.  I just brute-force included all the libraries, but still get linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::__1::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::__1::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've done some spot-checking of the OpenCv reference documents and the wiki pages, starting from here

```
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d__feature_detection_and_descriptor_extraction.html
```

but without success.

I'd be grateful for

1. specific help in finding these OpenCv APIs
2. general strategies for this kind of query: "what library contains the symbol I need to link against".  This kind of problem makes me hate C++, since 5 minutes of coding always seems to lead to hours of hit-and-miss library searching, possibly because I just don't know the professional secret for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My toolchain utilizes CMake to keep track of these sorts of things. For most new libraries I use, there are usually google searchable accompanying Find*.cmake files that are written by others. If you wanted more information about my specific set-up, feel free to ask. I have seen this specific problem (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64) a few times for things in the nonfree libraries. I'm not sure why you are getting that error for the imread, though. The first place I would look is the matcher_simple.cpp example in the samples/cpp folder. If you can compile and run this (using [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CompileOpenCVUsingLinux)) and the other examples, your set-up should be ok. If you can't, can you please post the errors of that example? I'm not familiar with XCode but [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564289/osx-10-7-5-opencv-2-4-3-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-when-usin) suggested going to Build Settings>Build Options> Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C and change it from Apple LLVM Compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2. And there are a few other guesses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781198/compiling-opencv-code-on-a-64-bit-mac) too.

Comment: Wow!  That did it (switching to LLVM GCC).  I didn't realize how different the Apple compiler and GCC are.  I'll look into CMake -- sounds like it could save me a lot of grief.

Answer (score 8):

On Linux and using **OpenCV 3.0.0** I had to link with the `opencv_imgcodecs` shared lib.

Comment: That's what saved me on Qt 5.5.0, OpenCV 3.0.0 and OsX 10.10. Thank you sir.

Comment: also worked for me on openCV 3.1, on windows. imread needs to link with imgcodecs: "-lopencv_imgcodecsXXX"

Answer (score 0):

Try including `-lopencv_features2d` and `-lopencv_nonfree` in your list of Other Linker Flags in the Build Settings. I was getting the same problems and it worked for me