# Cannot compile because of undefined references?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I'm tying to run a simple OpenCV code, but unfortunately I'm getting an `undefined reference` error. And I really don't know what to do. This is the code that I'm trying to make it run

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Mat image;

    image = imread(argv[1], 1);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the eclipse output: basically it says: `undefined reference to cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'`

The complete error message is:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "TestOpenCV"  ./src/TestOpenCV.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
./src/TestOpenCV.o: In function `main':
/media/cip/Media/workspace/OpenCV/TestOpenCV/Debug/../src/TestOpenCV.cpp:21: undefined reference to cv::imread(cv::String const&, int) collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [TestOpenCV] Error 1
```

And the list output of `pkg-config opencv --libs` looks like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940126/opencv-2-4-3-cant-find-imread-and-surffeaturedetectordetect) already. Try adding

```
-lopencv_imgcodecs
```

to the list of linker flags.

Answer (score 2):

undefined reference errors reffers to " invalid lib path ". 
Make sure that you enter the valid lib path:
 they should have extension ".lib" or ".a"
Hope it help.